# Contribution for support of Hindi (Indian language) in itextpdf

Tags: itextpdf

I was looking for Hindi language support in my project using itextpdf version 5.3.2 but unfortunately, I have observed there is no such thing present. I have seen many blogs for Hindi support where itext has asked developers to contribute but a few have turned up so far.

I want to contribute itext to this cause. So please guide me how can I initiate or take a step forward.
Looking for your response.